# Can't see emulator selection option in visual studio 2012 for windows phone

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

In my Visual studio 2012 for windows phone , I created one project and I developed some pages.
**It is working fine and i'm able to debug by selecting the desired emulator option.
Suddenly the device options tab is not visible.** It is looking like below.

[image]

**For testing purpose I've opened another project, then for this project i'm getting the emulator option.** It is looking like this.

[image]

I didn't understand why it is happening with the first project. could you please tell me how to enable emulator options for the first project.

Thanks.

Comment: :just stop debugging your project...(i.e press SHIFT+F5 )

Comment: if its not working than let me know

Comment: i'm not in debugging mode. Whenever i open the project then by default it is disbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple projects in your solution then the one that is set as the 'StartUp project' is probably not a Windows Phone app.
The options included in the menu relate to the startup project only.

To change the startup project, right click on the project in the solution explorer and select "Set as StartUp project".

Comment: the above project is set to start up project only. I have checked.